# Add index variable with more than one loop variable Python

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, enumerate

When running a one variable loop, adding an index variable is easy:

```
a = ( (2,3), (7,9) )
for i,v in enumerate( a ):
    print( v )
    print( i )
```

Yields:

```
(2, 3)
0
(7, 9)
1
```

Trying to generate a two-variable loop works well too:

```
for c,v in enumerate( a ):
    print( c )
    print( v )
```

Yields:

```
0
(2, 3)
1
(7, 9)
```

However, adding an index, via enumerate, for 3 loop variables, does not work:

```
for i,c,v in enumerate( a ):
    print( c )
```

Yields:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`enumerate` returns an iterator with pairs, never triples. For this particular input data, the second member of such a pair is a pair itself. So there is *nesting*. You should unpack that structure using the same nesting:

```
for i, (c, v) in enumerate( a ):
    print(f"i={i} c={c} v={v}")
```